# Windows 7 32-bit, Ergo Mouse installation issue: "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect."

Tags: windows-7, installation, mouse, 32-bit, visual-c++

I have a fresh installation of Windows 7 32-bit (updated through the system and Windows Update) and I need to install an **Ergo525 mouse**. The mouse is working properly, is recognized by Windows 7 as Ergo525, it changes sensitivity correctly but to custom setup four extra buttons (two change the volume now-useless on a notebook), I need to install Genius ioCenter.exe (they do not supply only a mouse driver). When I do that even under XP/Vista compatibility(as it worked fine under Windows XP SP3) this pops up:

> "Microsoft Visual C++ SP1 Redistributable Package(x86). Command line syntax error. Type Command /? for Help."

I then restart but when I try to run ioCentre file(gTaskBar.exe) again even under compatibility mode) I get this message:

> "C:\Genius\ioCetre\gTaskBar.exe The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."

I have been trying to sort it out myself for hours but am utterly helpless.

By the way, this is rather a productivity issue, so if there is any other program to configure the extra buttons on my mouse, I'd be more than happy with that solution.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. It was of course a software/driver version issue-the manufacturer offers V1.3.04, Driver Genius software for driver updates downloaded v1.3.2.1 and everything was flawless. Driver Genius is a paid program, I am mentioning it just to explain what worked for me in case somebody else runs up against this issue too. It might save him/her the hours it took me.